# How to measure react initiate render time of a page using Profiler extension?

Tags: reactjs, performance, web, profiler

I'm currently working on optimizing the performance of a React application and I'm particularly interested in accurately measuring the initial render time of specific pages/components. I've read about the React Profiler API and understand it can be used to gather performance metrics, but I'm a bit unclear on how to specifically measure the initial render time of a page/component.

My questions are:

- How can I use the React Profiler (or the Profiler extension that im currently using) to measure the initial render time of a page?
- Is there a specific method or approach to isolate the initial render metrics from subsequent re-renders or updates?
- Are there any recommended practices or common pitfalls to be aware of when using the Profiler for this purpose?

I already try using the Profiler extension, I use it by using the refresh icon (reload and start profiling) and immediately stop the profiling so i don't make any interaction and try to find the initiate render time.

Here the screenshot of my profiler
[React Profiler Extension](https://i.stack.imgur.com/io17H.png)

I really want to clear some things

- is the 1/12 show the amount of component change when rendering? then if i want to find the initiate render time should i look to the 1/12 and then check the "Render" under Duration section?
- or the initiate render time is all "Render" in 1 untill 12 combine?

Thank you in advance for your help!